# Android quiz - save index and restart from the respective index

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android true/false quiz application, the only thing remaining is I'm having a hard time figuring out **how to save index**. I know it can be done via sharedpreferences but I am not sure how. I have previous and next buttons and updatequestion() is called everytime the user changes the question.

mCurrentIndex starts at 0 so we start from 1,2,3 and so on.

Let me explain, I have a set of 10 questions in an array and all questions are stored in strings.xml. What i want to do is if user was viewing question 5, for eg. and he closed the app and restarted it back,
**the quiz should resume from q5 and not q1**.

```
        private Question[] QuestionBank = new Question[] {

        new Question(R.string.question_1, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_2, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_3, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_4, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_5, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_6, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_7, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_8, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_9, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_10, true),

       };

       private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

       private void updateQuestion() {

       int question = QuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
       int temp = mCurrentIndex+1;
       String num = Integer.toString(temp);
       questionNumber.setText(num+ "/" + QuestionBank.length);
       questionText.setText(question);

    }
```

Also, I have another query regarding the same.

How to shuffle index of the questions each time the user opens the quiz? Normally, it would follow 1,2,3,4 and so on but can it go 4,6,3,1,8 or 2,4,1,9,7.. you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

get access to shared prefs:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Write to prefs

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key", "lalala");
editor.commit();
```

Read from shared prefs

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sharedPref.getString("key", defaultValue);
```

for more info check:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html